# How to redirect an email sent to my azure website onto a customers email on another domain

Tags: .net, email, azure, smtp

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure explains how to listen on a port for incoming email.

I want to grab the email address the mail is sent to like mike@mycustomdomain.com and pass it on to the customers personal email at another host like mike@gmail.com

I'm really not sure if this is even possible. I would prefer NOT to parse the incoming email and send out a new one to the second email address.

Is it possible to forward/redirect an incoming email to another email address without actually sending the email. Maybe a header reply or mail protocol?

My website is an ASP.NET site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as `an email sent to my azure website`!

E-mails follow different path from the HTTP traffic. And this is controlled by the DNS entries. Your `mycompany.com` domain may be WEB hosted in Azure WebSites, while the mails for `anyone@mycompany.com` be handled by Google Apps for Business for instance. Which server handles the e-mails for your domain is controlled by the [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for that domain. 
Moreover [e-mail runs on ports quite different from the Web Traffic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

Having said that, I want to assure you that no e-mail will ever reach your application hosted in Azure Web Sites.

What you can do is any of the following:

- Create an extra small WorkerRole, enable IIS and E-Mail (SMTP) server role, configure to just forward the e-mails
- Just use Google's e-mail service for custom domains (paid of course) or Office365 or the cheapest web hosting provider that offers a mail hosting, and then configure mail forwarding for the account

The concrete implementation of any of the suggested approaches can be found with a simple Internet search.